# Regular expression capture everything including new lines between two patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to pull @media rules out of a style sheet to cache and then apply in IE<9 with JS at the appropriate resolutions.

For example:

```
.../*default rules*/...
#work-head { background-image: url("/images/work-art-supplies-med.png"); height: 168px; width: 213px; }        

}

@media screen and (min-width : 657px) {


.welcome h1 { border: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; }

.welcome p { font-size: 13px; font-size: 1.3rem; }

.../*more rules*/...

}

.../*more rules*/...
```

At the moment I am getting the min-width and  everything after it (right to the end of the style sheet) with:

```
/657px\)(\s|\n)*\{/
```

and getting the end point of the media query by finding the double "}}" at the end of the media query with the following:

```
/}[^{]*}/
```

This works, but it requires two regular expressions and some string manipulation to make each IE style sheet and that makes me feel dirty.

I am trying to avoid breaking out the rules for IE into separate files to make maintenance easier and I think I need a regex so that I can extract both before and after CSS is compressed (it does now, but obviously is far from optimal).

So can someone please tell me how I can combine these 2 expressions into one?

Basically: how can I match everything between either a literal or pattern and another literal or pattern?

Also - this needs to work in IE<9 so I think lookahead and lookbehind are not options(?)

Comment: Add a longer list of styles.  Do they all start with @media? Or maybe @somethingelse?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about this question :-), but in case anyone is interested:

```
/657px\)(\s|\n)*\{(.|\n)+?(}[^{]*})/
```

does the trick (nearly). It works perfectly on http://regexpal.com/, but in IE<9 the match gets "} }, , ,} }" at the end instead of "}}".

I need to substring it anyway so no big deal, but I'd be interested to hear if anyone knows how to make it function the same way in IE as on regexpal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the last line you want is simply "}", then this will do:

```
 /657px\)[\n\r\w\s]*\{[\n\r\w\W]*[\n\r]\}/
```

I used phantomjs to run the filter below on your test case:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
input = fs.open('/dev/stdin', 'r');
var stuff = input.read();
var somestuff = stuff.match(/657px\)[\n\r\w\s]*\{[\w\W]*[\n\r]\}/);
console.log(somestuff);
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but this does exactly the same thing as what I was using:

Comment: Hi, Cheapwax - accidentally entered last comment :/. Thanks for the effort, but this does exactly the same thing as what I was using (/657px\)(\s|\n)*\{/) - it starts at the literal and goes all the way to the end of the sheet including any subsequent @media rules. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, but what I need to do is to get the media rules starting with the literal "657px" and stopping at the double curly brackets "}}" which is the end of the media query so that I can append just the specific media query as a stylesheet to IE<9.

Comment: Hi, Jack. at the moment there are just 2 sets of media rules in one sheet: "@media screen and (min-width : 657px) {" and "@media screen and (min-width : 1001px) {". I want to capture just the rules for one media query - so stop when finding a "}" followed by another "}" without an opening "{" between (/}[^{]*}/ works for this fine).

Comment: Hi, Cheapwax - I made a mistake in my previous comment - what I meant to say was that your regex does the same thing as /657px)(\s|\n|.)*\{/. The one I am using right now ("/657px)(\s|\n)*\{/" - without the "|.") just gets me the index of the literal.